# R - analysing tripadvisor content with tm

Tags: r, csv, analysis, tm

I scraped some tripadvisor content (id, quote, ratings, complete review) in a csv file and tried to filter out the documents with just 5* rating, but it seems not to work.

```
> x <- read.csv ("test.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)   
> (corp <- VCorpus(DataframeSource (x),  
+  readerControl = list(language = "eng")))
```

I get the following:

```
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 50
```

Now, on filtering, it shows, that there are 0 documents with a rating of 5* and that cant be right.

```
> idx <- meta(corp, "rating") == '5'

> corp [idx]

<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 0
```

Did I overlook anything on creating the corpus?

**text output as requested**

```
'data.frame':   682 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X            : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ id           : chr  "rn360260358" "rn359340351" "rn356397660"     "rn355961772" ...
 $ quote        : chr  "Nice but not unique " "Beautiful scenery of German     forest with a lake" "Beautiful Lake and Amazing Mountain Views" "Beautiful!" ...
 $ rating       : chr  "3" "5" "5" "5" ...
 $ date         : chr  "Reviewed 5 March 2016" "Reviewed 29 February 2016" "Reviewed 27 February 2016" ...
 $ reviewnospace: chr  "We visited the lake with our daughters in March. All s...
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: it might be that ratings are integer and not strings (in which case your need `5` instead of `'5'`), but it's hard to tell without a look at your data. You could share at least one document by posting the output of `dput(corp[[1]])`

Comment: thank you for answering. I added the output as an image to the question above. I am new to R, as you probably recognised... :)

Comment: You could try this: 
`library(quanteda)`
`corp <- corpus(textfile("test.csv", textField = "quote"))`
`corpOnly5 <- subset(corp, rating == '5')`

Comment: @LauraHiemer text is always better than images. You should copy that text directly into your question.

Comment: It seems like your ratings are in the corpus content and not the metadata. Maybe try `VCorpus(VectorSource(x$content)` where `content` is the name of the variable that actually holds the text in `x`. We would need to see what's in x to help you more (to do that, paste the *text* output of `dput(head(x))`)

Comment: @KenBenoit this is working, but then I can not use any of the tm functions on the `corpOnly5`. The error "not applicable method" appears. @scoa I added the output above.

Comment: That's true but you could use the quanteda functions to analyse your corpus. Same functionality and some find it simpler.

Comment: @LauraHiemer thanks for the data, but it is faulty : we are missing parts of the second to last line.

Comment: @scoa thank you very much for your answer! Do you maybe also have an idea how to filter the data on the basis of the date? To get for example just the reviews for the months June - September. I tried to adapt your code, but it did not work

Comment: @LauraHiemer You should ask another question. Be sure to include all the needed code and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data import method simply does not pass the metadata. `DataFrameSource(x)` passes all variables of `x` as the document text.

Moreover, whatever the method, there is no easy, automatic way to add a bunch of metadata in `tm`. Instead, we can use `VectorSource(x$reviewnospace)` (assuming this is the column that is holding the text), and in a second step assign it the metadata. Your indexing then works as expected.

```
library(tm)

# use VectorSource to import data
corp <- VCorpus(VectorSource(x$reviewnospace),  readerControl = list(language = "eng"))
# assign metadata
meta(corp,tag = "rating") <- x$rating

idx <- meta(corp, "rating") == '5'
corp [idx]
```